# How to implement pagination for a database query?

Tags: elixir

I am newbie in elixir programming. I have an issue in recursion in elixir.

- I have a block code like this

```
def seen_page(page_id, total \\ 0, type \\ "ALL") do
    repo = Shard.by_page(page_id)
    sub_query =
      if type === "ALL" do
        from(c in Conversation, where: c.page_id == ^page_id and c.seen == false, limit: 500)
      else
        from(c in Conversation, where: c.page_id == ^page_id and c.seen == false and c.type == ^type, limit: 500)
      end

    from(c in Conversation, where: c.page_id == ^page_id, join: s in subquery(sub_query), on: s.id == c.id)
    |> repo.update_all([set: [seen: true, unread_count: 0]])
    |> case  do
      {count, nil} ->
        case count do
          500 ->
            seen_page(page_id, total + 500, type)
          count ->
            IO.puts "Đã đánh dấu tất cả #{type} của trang #{page_id} thành đã đọc"
            Cache.update_page_unread_count_limit_2k(page_id)
            total + count
        end
      _ ->
         false
    end
  end
```

- For example, I have 2000 records, I will take 500 records each time until the end and return it to the front end
- Now I want to get 500 records every time to return the front end. Then continue to take the remaining records. Is there any way to do that?
- I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this. It seems like you are trying to do 2 separate things -- you can either return something or do your recursion, but usually not both. It also doesn't seem normal to me to limit the number of records to be updated.  If this is a slow operation, it would be more common to perform this action asynchronously.

Comment: Instead of taking out all the records and then returning them to the front end. Now I want to break down the record retrieval into smaller stages, each stage of getting the record will return to the front end always to avoid timeout request

Comment: This does not sound like a good way to avoid a timeout.  More common would be to do the task *asynchronously*, so you can click something on the front-end that says "update millions of records" and the response from the cast operation is simply `:ok`, meaning "Ok, I requested that this operation be done in a separate process, but I'm not waiting around for it to complete -- I don't know how long it will take".  If you want to have a side-effect in your recursion that updates the status somehow, that would be a way to provide visibility to the progress.

Comment: I will try your way. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, understand that a web request should receive a response *quickly*.  Web sites that take too long to deliver a response can make for a bad visitor experience -- even modestly slow responses cause visitors to flat-out leave. I don't have a link handy, but I remember seeing an article that showed that that a visitor would leave a page in about 3 seconds if things did not happen. It's also possible that if a response takes too long, it can time-out altogether.  In short, slow responses are bad -- they're even play a part in some [web attacks](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/ddos-attack-tools/slowloris/).

So you should **never** wire your long-running processes into a web page directly. If you need to trigger something that takes more than a few hundred milliseconds, you should always process it *asynchronously* so the visitor is not left waiting. You just quickly tell your visitor "Ok, we're working on it" and be done.

One simple way to do this in Elixir is via [`Task.start/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#start/3). For example, if your slow task is the `:slow_thing` function inside the `Foo` module, you could call it asynchronously like so:

```
result = Task.start(Foo, :slow_thing, ["Hello..."])
IO.inspect(result)
```

Note that sending the message happens *immediately*. The `result` is something like `{:ok, #PID<0.99.0>}` -- it has zero knowledge of what the `Foo.slow_thing/1` function does or how long it might take.  It knows that the module and function exists, but that's about it.

For example, if the module and function you call asynchronously look something like this:

```
defmodule Foo do
  def slow_thing(input) do
    Process.sleep(5_000) # <-- simulated long-running thing
    File.write("side_effect.log","#{input}\n", [:utf8, :append])
  end
end
```

Then you can inspect the expected side effects (viewing a log file, in this example). Remember, the process that calls `Task.start/3` must still be running in order for `Foo.slow_thing/1` to complete. If you're doing this inside a Phoenix app, this shouldn't be a problem, but if you're trying to make this work inside a simple `.exs` script, just keep in mind that as soon as the script completes, the started task would shut down.

Since your question asked about how to keep track of progress, things are a bit more complicated.  Ask yourself seriously if this is a requirement or just a nice-to-have -- *it may not be worth the extra work*.

The trick to this type of problem is *recursion*: a function that calls itself.  It should still be called asynchronously, but during each iteration it can call a side-effect that you can observe. Consider something like this which shows recursion used to paginate a select query:

```
def update_conversations(page_id, offset \\ 0) do
  from(c in Conversation, where: c.page_id == ^page_id and c.seen == false, limit: 500, offset: ^offset)
  |> Repo.all()
  |> case do
    [] ->
      # another side-effect somewhere to indicate completion
      SomeSideEffect.done(page_id)
      :done
    results ->
      # side-effect somewhere to indicate progress
      SomeSideEffect.progress(page_id, 500)
      update_conversations(page_id, offset + 500)  # <-- recursion!
  end
end
```

You can adapt an update query to this type of pattern, but the important thing is that you choose useful side-effects.  The web page could read the value of the "progress cache" and each time the visitor refreshed the page, they could see the progress.  If you don't want to force a refresh, you could have Javascript query an endpoint periodically or use LiveView to push an update to the visitor.

Comment: There are no words to show my appreciation! Thank you very much